# Winform program started, and button1 focused, why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# winform application. When i build it, the focus is on my button1, why? There is no code for this anywhere... If i directly write to form1_load's method this: button2.Focus(), there is no changing...

I think it will be a very easy question...

Comment: If it's a very easy question then you pretty much answered it.. it should be a easy fix.. go thru your code and property setting, hint `USE THE DEBUGGER`

Comment: Using the debugger is not a good hint for this type of question. Anything involving focus cannot be easily debugged with a debugger because introducing the debugger has an effect. You need to understand what's actually going on.

Comment: Cody any hint is a good hint besides stating `i think it will be a very easy question`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is an easy question, the `TabIndex` property of your controls is defined automatically by the Visual Studio IDE when you add the controls on the form surface.

You can change this [`TabIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) property manually or, better, using the menu `View` and then the `Tab Order` submenu.
Every control on your form surface will display on the upper left corner a small blue box with a number that you can click to change the TabIndex order. It is more easy to do that to explain.

When your form is displayed, the control with TabIndex=0 and that supports focus will be the first to receive focus. (Labels and other controls that cannot be focused are excluded by this)

Comment: Yes, it's really great, thx!
If i try it in a sample project win 1 form, 2buttons, it's works. But i have a more difficult one, which has got around 8buttons, and a panel, which is setuped from code, nor frome designt view... I would like to focus this one, because -i think- it's isn't visible...
So the main aim: when the program starts, i would like, to don't see a focused component...

Comment: And you are breaking some common accepted law of user interface design. Said that, you could try to put a button with no click event attached outside the form limits and give the tabindex zero to this button. Again don't do that.

Comment: It was a necessery problem solving: it's own panel class, which is double buffered, and inherited from factory class'.
I can't understandy exactly you, 'cause of my English... Uhm, i understand you now... It is the only way? An add-on button, with no functions, outside the form limits and with 0 zero tab-index?

For example the panel1.Focus() method why can't solve the problem, in the form1_load() method?

Comment: I solve it, with your tip: TAB ORDER, thank you! I have a combobox too, i rendered 0 to this one, and if the program runs, the focus on that combobox, but it doesn't seems like that... So it's great! Big thx man!